# template argument from aliased lambda is invalid

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, lambda, c++20

(c++20 mode for all of the following)

I am trying to use std unordered_map with std::reference_wrapper keys to avoid copying somewhat expensive keys, that are stored elsewhere anyway. The referenced type is hashable, but I need to provide forward hasher functors and comparator functors, which I have done as so:

```cpp
template < typename T >
using default_ref_hasher = decltype([](const std::reference_wrapper< T >& value) {
    return std::hash< std::remove_cvref_t< T > >{}(value.get());
});
template < typename T >
using default_ref_comparator = decltype([](const std::reference_wrapper< T >& ref1,
                                            const std::reference_wrapper< T >& ref2) {
    return ref1.get() == ref2.get();
});
```

those are then used in my templated class

```cpp
template <typename Action>
class Myclass {

   std::unordered_map<
      std::reference_wrapper< const Action >,
      double,
      default_ref_hasher< const Action >,
      default_ref_comparator< const Action > >
      map{};

};
```

I feel as though this is valid c++ code, however, I get the following errors on GCC 11+:

```
<source>:24:46: error: template argument 3 is invalid
   24 |       default_ref_comparator< const Action > >
      |                                              ^
<source>:24:46: error: template argument 4 is invalid
<source>:20:9: error: '<expression error>' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   20 |    std::unordered_map<
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   21 |       std::reference_wrapper< const Action >,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |       double,
      |       ~~~~~~~
   23 |       default_ref_hasher< const Action >,
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |       default_ref_comparator< const Action > >
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

as can be seen here on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rc8a3dE57). If I compile instead with clang 13+ it [does compile fine](https://godbolt.org/z/cxq6dPnEr).

Is this a bug in GCC or does clang fail to check a mistake I made?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a lambda instead of an actual named type? I mean, you're *already* giving it a name. And it's global. There's zero value in using a lambda here. Indeed, any code of the form `using name = decltype(lambda)` should be considered a code smell. Just use `struct name { auto operator() {body} };`.

Comment: This is [gcc bug 92707](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92707).

Comment: @NicolBolas I stumbled across this more as a refactoring issue and wanted to know what I was doing wrong, so I asked. You are right though, a named struct does the job all the same. However, I do find lambdas to provide easier syntax.

Comment: @Barry, thanks, if you post your comment as an answer I will be happy to accept it.